# Understanding Backbone.js view's collection and filtering/resetting (from Router, Event, etc)

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm still getting comfortable with Backbone.js, and there are plenty of times when I really think I'm getting it - then something so trivial pops up and rocks my world and makes me rethink if I even get it at all. This is one of those moments - any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

I have a View.  It has a Collection (the View displays a list of sessions during a day one every hour type of thing).  Initially, when the View is first created, I display the entire Sessions collection.  Thats fine.  At the top of the View I have 4 links for each day of the week (during our event) - 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th.  I want the user to be able to click on a day and filter the list of sessions for that particular day (like I said, pretty trivial).

So far I have it working this way:

1. the Sessions Collection (base class) has method called filterByDay(day) that does the following:

   ```
   filterByDay: function (day) {
       UGM.log('trying to filter by day of week: ' + day);
       return this.models.filter(function (s) {
           return moment.utc(s.get('StartTime')).format('DD') == day;
       });        
   }
   ```
2. the View is created and initialized with the full sessions collection.

   ```
   new UGM.SessionsCollectionView({ collection: UGM.data.sessionsData });
   ```
3. In my collection View - I have the following:

   ```
   events: {
       'click a.dayFilter':'filterByDay'
   },

   filterByDay: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var day = (this.$(e.currentTarget).attr('rel')*1);        
      this.render(this.collection.filterByDay(day));
      UGM.router.navigate("/sessions/" + day);
   }
   ```

So.. when the View boots up, its displaying the full sessions fine.  The a tags with a class of dayFilter trigger the event appropriately, and the filterByDay in the View calls the Views render() method passing in the NEW filtered collection (from the model's method).  Again so far so good.

1. In my controller (router) I have the following (and this is the confusing part):

   ```
   showSessions: function (animate, level) {
       var section = new UGM.SessionsLayout({ collection: UGM.data.sessions });
       this.displaySection(section, 'root', 'sessions', animate);
   },
   showSessionsByDay: function(day, animate, level){
       //** Should the next line really be that convoluted?!?! **//
       var section = new UGM.SessionsLayout({ collection: new UGM.SessionsCollection(UGM.data.sessions.filterByDay(day)) });
       //** Why cant it just look like this: **//
       //var section = new UGM.SessionsLayout({ collection: UGM.data.sessions.filterByDay(day) });

       this.displaySection(section, 'root', 'sessions/' + day, false);
   },
   ```

Note my comment above the line in question.  All of my problems (logically) seem to stem from my lack of understanding exactly how collections filter, collection.models filter, and the fact that filter() seems to always return an array and not a collection.  (which is why Im declaring a new base Collection inside my filter call from the Controller above).

Sorry of this is confusing or doesnt make sense, but hopefully with this amount of detail someone can see a super obvious hole in my general logic with how im dealing with the collection to begin with.

Thanks again for any help!!

Comment: After some thought and debugging, I changed my process a bit.  For now, in my controller I always pass the full sessions data - whether coming from showSessions or showSessionsByDay - the only difference is that I pass a option of "startday" to the View.  In my view, I check for start day and if it exists I filter the base list that the view was initialized with and render passing in that new list to the render call.  Otherwise I just call render() (and it relies on the stock this.collection list).  Not necessarily "happy" with that solution as it kind of feels like a hack...

Comment: I maintain a separate variable let say 'filtered' of the same type to display search results or to show subset of the main collection. And in my view which displays the collection results, I add logic to switch between using the original collection or 'filtered' to render the items on the page. If it's working for now, I would say let it be and revisit it after sometime if you get any better ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't just do the commented out line is because filterByDay() is returning an array of models, not a collection of models. This means that your view's collection won't have the functions that come along with Backbone Collections. If you don't want to reset your original collection (which it looks like you don't), you are doing the next best thing. A more readable way of doing this (though it is exactly the same code) might be:

```
showSessionsByDay: function(day, animate, level){
  var filteredCollection = new UGM.SessionsCollection(UGM.data.sessions.filterByDay(day));
  var section = new UGM.SessionsLayout({ collection: filteredCollection });

  this.displaySection(section, 'root', 'sessions/' + day, false);
},
```

Comment: Right!  THanks for the response, and pretty much what I figured.  One work around I did was implement the new SessionsCollection right in the return of the collections filterByDay method.  So saves me the extra step (that you oulined above) and works across the board now - basically eliminating the toArray default functionality of the filter() function (specifically for that method).  Thanks again!